# htaccess configuration - With CodeIgniter - A3M library

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, oauth, codeigniter-a3m

I downloaded a3m, it comes packaged with CI 1.7.2 but I went ahead and removed all of the files it needed to run and put them in my pre-existing installation. After going to the a3m controller on my site I received:
Message: Undefined property: CI::$session

So I assume it’s because of htaccess looking for a3m files in an a3m folder, here’s the a3m htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^$ /a3m/index.php [L] 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|img|js|scripts|system|uploads|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /a3m/index.php/$1 [L]
```

And my already existing htaccess for mod rewrite is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /beta/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

As the commenting shows, I used it from a site a while back, so how can I combine the two I guess is what I’m trying to ask as I’m quite enthused about using a3m.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've loaded the session library.

Check in system\application\config\autoload.php if you have the library loaded:
[42] $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');

You can do this from the controller:
$this->load->library('session');

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html